# Reduce wake-up noise on ARM CM3

Tags: noise, uart, gpio, sleep, cortex

I need some help exploring a solution.

I have an ARM Cortex M3 MCU, which has low-power sleep mode implemented. Wake-up sources are any GPIO pin, or an RTC alarm.  A terminal is connected to UART-0 at 115200bps.

When the system wakes, a stream on unintelligible chars is sent to the terminal.  I assume this is noise or jitter.  The board designer did not place any external pull-ups or noise suppressing caps on the UART Pins, so I need to solve this issue in the firmware.

So far I've tried the following, to no avail:

1. Before entering sleep mode, detach (demux) the UART Tx pin and attach (mux) GPIO input with internal pull-up. On exiting sleep mode do the converse.
2. As in 1, above, but attach GPIO Output, driving high.
3. As in 1 & 2 above, but flushing UART FIFOs after detaching, and before attaching.

The following kinda works, but is not very elegant:

1. After waking, send a stream of backspaces -- `for(int a=0;a<64;a++) printf("\b");` But sometimes non-back-spaceable chars (e.g. CR or LF) slip thru and it aint pretty.

Comment: As I/O pin functionality is part specific and not a feature of the ARM core, you must state the actual MCU part number.

Comment: *"I assume this is noise or jitter."* You really need to put a scope on it and find out exactly what the nature of the problem is. If it's the result of slow power-up of an interface chip, for example, there may be no firmware solution.

Comment: What MCU is this? What is between MCU TX pin and terminal? RS232 level converter or TTL USB serial adapter? Do MCU clocks change slower in sleep mode? What is the clock source oscillator for MCU?